# C:out tag in jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am new to jstl.This is my code.

hello.jsp

```
  <%@ page contentType="text/html" %> 
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
 <html> 
 <body> 
  <form method="GET" action="jstl-choose-tag.jsp" > 
 Select an operation and click the button<br /><br /> 
<input type="radio" name="radioBtnGroup" value="uCaseOp" />Convert a string to upper    Case<br /> 
<input type="radio" name="radioBtnGroup" value="lCaseOp" />Convert a string to lower Case<br /> 

 <br /> 
<input type="Submit" /> 
 </form> 


 </body> 
 </html>
```

jstl-choose-tag.jsp:

```
   <%@ page contentType="text/html" %> 
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
   <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %> 

  <html> 
  <body>
    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.method=='GET'}">
    <c:out value="${param.radioBtnGroup}" />
  <c:out value="${param.radioBtnGroup}" />
  </c:if> 

<a href="hello.jsp"> Back</a> 
  </body> 
 </html>
```

the output which I get is

```
 ${param.radioBtnGroup} ${param.radioBtnGroup}
```

Can anyone help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the generated HTML code look like when doing "View HTML source" in your browser? Have you included the standard.jar and jstl.jar files in the WEB-INF/lib of your webapp?

Comment: version of your tomcat/servlet container?

Comment: when i add the jstl-choose-tag.jsp code in the hello.jsp page it is displaying the value correctly.the same code i display in the next page jstl-choose-tag.jsp file i am getting the above output

Answer (score 2):

The symptoms indicate that the JSTL tags are successfully been parsed and executed (otherwise you wouldn't see `${foo}` in the browser at all), but the EL expressions are not evaluated (you're seeing literally `${foo}` in the browser).

This can happen when your `web.xml` is not declared conform **at least** Servlet 2.4 / JSP 2.0. If your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 2.3 or lower, or has a broken declaration, then EL expressions in JSP 2.0 compatible taglibs won't be evaluated at all.

For proper `web.xml` declaration examples, check the bottom of [our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). Assuming that you're targeting a Servlet 2.5 capable container (e.g. Tomcat 6.0, Glassfish 2.x, etc), then your `web.xml` should be declared conform Servlet 2.5:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

The el tag libraries must be referenced by

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

NOT BY

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

If the questioner switches it over there's a good chance it'll pick up the right library, so long as the appropriate jar is in the classpath. Curiously enough, this worked for me even though I was declaring servlet 2.3 (not 2.4 or later) in my web.xml so that doesn't seem crucial. I'm using Tomcat as my servlet container.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have not included jar file which has to be there to run any jstl.
if you are using maven then you can add dependencies otherwise you have to add jar file.
[click here for reference](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.